# How to add an additional repository at the top of the list for a particular subproject in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a multi project setup in Gradle, the root of which specifies a bunch of repositories that are shared by all subprojects:

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url '...' }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

How can I specify an additional repository for a particular subproject, and have it as the first in the list of repositories?

Why do I need to do this?  I need to include an Android library in `.aar` format.  It is present in `.aar` format in this additional repository, and in `.apklib` format in Maven Central.  If Gradle hits Maven Central first and finds the `.apklib` it will bail out.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you know that gradle is unable to find it? What happens?

Comment: It complains that it can't find an artifact which is in that repo.  If that repo is listed in the `subprojects { repositories { ... } }` list (in the parent build.gradle), it builds fine.

Comment: Are you saying that what I'm doing ought to work and I likely have some other issue?

Comment: Yes, it seems that everything is fine. Do you have a runnable example?

Comment: Right, further investigation reveals it's not that simple, question updated.

Answer (score 0):

By postponing the addition of the repositories in the root build script, the repositories are added after the ones added in the subproject:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        repositories {
            maven { url '...' }
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend to use something for external&internal repository management.

i think that artifactory or nexus can handle remote/virtual repositories, and makes it possible to use only one repository in your project.

note: if repository order is relevant to you, that might mean that the artifact identifier (group:ident:version) can mean different artifacts - i think that violates some maven/etc guideline which can cause invalid caches behind gradle and cause mysterious problems